# Node.js / async each with parameter

Tags: arrays, node.js, asynchronous

As written in the documentation, about [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async):

> each(arr, iterator, callback)
>
> applies the function iterator to each item in arr, in parallel. The
> iterator is called with an item from the list, and a callback for when
> it has finished. If the iterator passes an error to its callback, the
> main callback (for the each function) is immediately called with the
> error.

My function get as param each of the items in the arr. In other words, I iterate over all the array, and I take each item in this array, and apply a function on the value of this item.

For example,

```
arr = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
```

and I want that `async.each` will iterate on this arr, and convert the next loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    dosomething(arr[i]);
```

to async version.

How can I do it?

Comment: The documentation is very good at explaining this: https://github.com/caolan/async#each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the async version for your code will be:

```
async.each(arr, function( arrObj, callback) {
    dosomething(arrObj);
    callback();
}, function(err){
    if( err ) {
      // do something with the error
    } else {
      //do something else after .each gets executed
    }
});
```