# NodeJS async module processing contents of each iteration asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronous, async.js

I am building an application in NodeJS version 8.5 with Express middleware.

I am using the async module to loop over an array of objects. The async.each method iterates over each object and processes each element.

Each object will be processed in a different way depending upon the property.

The way I have it now is to just call a bunch of synchronous methods inside the body of the async.each loop. However, I know that this isn't the 'proper' Node way since everything supposed to be asynchronous.

How can I structure this to use asynchronous methods properly?

```
async.each(elements_all, (element_original, callback) => {
  // Create new array
  const elements_processed = [];

  // If element has order number property
  if (element_original.order_number) {
    element_original.order_number = processToDisplay(element_original.order_number); //This is a synchronous call
  }

  // If element has po number property
  if (element_original.po_number) {
    element_original.po_number = processToDisplay(element_original.po_number);
  }

  // If element has item price property
  if (element_original.item_price) {
    element_original.item_price = processToDisplay(element_original.item_price);
  }

  // Push to the return array
  entities_processed.push(element_original);

  callback();
}, (err) => { 
  if (err) {
    res.json({
      server_error: true
    });
  } else {
    res.json(entities_processed);
  }
});
```

Comment: Uh, if you have no genuinely asynchronous work to do, then it's not asynchronous and you should just use a synchronous loop.

Comment: is `processToDisplay` the async part?

Comment: @forJ processToDisplay is a synchronous method and I was thinking that I would need to convert that into an asynchronous method, since it is inside the body of an async.each loop iteration. I have read that you should 'never call sync methods inside of an async method' in NodeJS.

Comment: I think I found a good answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25137461/node-js-async-each-with-parameter There are many examples that use synchronous calls inside the body of async.each method so I suppose the way I have it now is acceptable.

Comment: You can also make sync process async by spawning another process